# Unable to find zend module config files

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php, socialengine

I'm searching within the directories of my SocialEngine website, which is written with the Zend Framework, but I'm unable to find the module config file `application.config.php`, which according to [Zend Docs](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/modules.html) is the place where module configs are written. Where does SocialEngine keep modules config?
I'm using composer by the way.

Comment: Their [documentation](https://support.socialengine.com/php/customer/portal/articles/1686929-socialengine-php-v4-table-of-contents) doesn't help?

Comment: It's probably using ZF1, which does configuration a different way.

Answer (score 1):

SocialEngine modules config files are located within `/application/modules/Modulename/settings/settings` folder where `Modulename` is the name of the module you're searching for.